# Xamarin.Essentials' WebAuthenticator vs MSAL?

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-ad-msal, webauthenticator

Being a newbie to Xamarin I am not sure if these can be compared.

I am looking at ways to authenticate a user through Xamarin app.

We use Azure AD and my Xamarin app wants to autheticate the staff of our organization.
It then needs to access an Azure AD authenticated API.

The 2 options I found:

1. **Xamarin.Essenials' WebAuthenticator**, looks like a good option.
   But I feel like it is for a B2C applications(because it mentions about social authentication).

   The site mentions this is more secure as there is a middle layer to do the authentication.
   But when I checked the source code for middle layer(Startup.cs) there were Clientid and client
   secrets.

   https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/authentication-xamarin-essentials-aspnet/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003277
2. I also read about **MSAL** for authenticating users.
   It is a nuget (and so is the above one) and just takes ClientId(and not the client secret).

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview

So I am wondering which would be best in my case: WebAuthenticator or MSAL?

Which is more secure,if it can be compared?

Is there any disadvantage of using either?

Is there a better way to do authentication securely?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We could use both two ways. But the first is more easy to get.

Comment: Does WebAuthenticator do the token life cycle management? MSAL does it as far as I understand.

Comment: You could refer to the link. It would be helpful. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator?tabs=android

Comment: Thanks for the link Wendy. So WebAuthenticator can be used to get the access_token and refresh token. But does WebAuthenticator store the access_token and refresh it if needed(like MSAL manages it)? If not how can we achieve it in WebAuthenticator?

Comment: Do you have any update, guideline for this?

Did you find a way to make work B2C with web-Authenticator?